# Proving that $dS$ is an exact differential mathematically

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry, entropy, reversibility

OK...so I hope this is not too dumb a question:

We know that we can express $dS$ as $$dS=\frac{dQ}{T}=\frac{C_v}{T}dT+\frac{R}{V}dV,$$
where $C_v$ is the thermal capacity at constant volume and $R$ is the gas constant.

However, I recall that for a differential of the form $dz=X(x,y)dx+Y(x,y)dy$ to be exact we must have $$\frac{\partial X(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial Y(x,y)}{\partial x}.$$

Now my problem is how do you show that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial V}\left(\frac{C_v}{T}\right)=\frac{\partial}{\partial T}\left(\frac{R}{V}\right).$$

My math skills are kind of rusty, so I'm having trouble here. I hope someone can help me out on this.

Comment: Hint: is $dz = X(x) dx + Y(y) dy$ exact?

Comment: @MannyC But isn't Cv dependent on volume and therefore a function of V?

Comment: @MannyC I thought if you keep volume constant and differentiate wrt T you will have Cv varying as V varies. Please correct me if my thinking is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a perfect gas, once one arrives at an expression for $dS$, the integrability condition is a trivial check.

$C_v=\alpha R$ with alpha constant. Thus, $C_v/T$ does not depend on $V$, while $R/V$ does not depend on $T$ and the condition for integrability is trivially satisfied.

A little less trivial (but not too difficult task) would be to show for a perfect gas that $\delta q_{rev}/T$ is an exact differential, where $\delta q_{rev} = dU + PdV$. For a general system (not a perfect gas) this would be equivalent to Carnot's theorem and then an expression of the 2nd law.